# Random number to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I want to make a dataframe using random number from 1 to 200.

how do I make a dataframe?

column number is one
row number is two hundred. [image]

I mean I want to change the value of 'AGCLS_CD'.
1 -> random value in range between 1 and 20 (the number of '1' is 25,000)
5 -> random value in range between 41 and 51 (the number of '5' is 1,900,000)

Comment: do u want to include all the numbers from 1 to 200 with random order or 200 random numbers from 1 to 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# All numbers between 1 and 200
data1 = np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, 201))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: data1})

# 200 numbers between 1 and 200
data2 = np.random.randint(1, 201, 200)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: data2})
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration!
I have a question more . 
for example, I have some columns, I want to change the value in one of columns.
The column has some values such as 1, 2, 3, etc. 
At that time, I wan to change the value 1 to random value (1, 11, 25000).
how do i correct the code you sent?

Comment: @YoungjinKO. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! thank you for your good advice! 
however, I ran into another question.

Comment: For example, I have some columns, I want to change the value in one of columns. The column has some values such as 1, 2, 3, etc. At that time, I wan to change the value 1 to random value (1, 11, 25000). how do i correct the code you sent?

Comment: Something like `np.where(df1['mycol'] == 5, np.random.randint(1, 201, len(df1)), df1['mycol'])`?

Comment: 1, 2, 3 etc in 'my col' 
I just want to change the value from 1  to randint(1, 201, 25000).

Comment: `df[mycol] = np.random.randint(1, 201, len(df))` Why 25000? This is the length of your dataframe?

Comment: Yes right.
I mean 
1, 2, 3 etc in 'my col' 
I just want to change the value '1' in the range between 1 and 20. 
yes 25000 is length of dataframe..

Thank you for your consideration!!

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df.head(5))` for a better understanding?

Comment: *I mean I want to change the value of 'AGCLS_CD'. 1 -> random value in range between 1 and 20 (the number of '1' is 25,000) 5 -> random value in range between 41 and 51 (the number of '5' is 1,900,000)*: Why especially 1 maps between 1 and 20 and 5 between 41 and 51. How do you know the range?

Comment: t has a fixed range in my field. 
2 -> 21 to 30
3 -> 31 to 40 etc..

Comment: A possible output will be [12, 18, 43, 50, 41] for your sample?

Comment: No, predicted output is not just one value. 
There are values about 1 in column. The value, 1, can be changed to  a variety of values without duplication restrictions in the range, 1 to 20.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand if [1, 1, 5, 5, 5] can't be [12, 18, 43, 50, 41], what is a possible output?

Comment: Sorry, I confused.!  You're right.

Comment: predicted output is [12, 18, 43, 50, 41] for my sample!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [random.randrange(1, 200) for i in range(200)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['random_number'])
```

It will create a list of random numbers with length=200 filled with random numbers from 1 to 200 and then create a dataframe with those values in one column called 'random_number'

Comment: Thank you for your consideration!
I have a question more . 
for example, I have some columns, I want to change the value in one of columns.
The column has some values such as 1, 2, 3, etc. 
At that time, I wan to change the value 1 to random value (1, 11, 25000).
how do i correct the code you sent?